# Execute TreeView on click event into another click event

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a method of `TreeView`. When I click in the parent `Item`, it executes the method like:

```
private void tvProjectList_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
  //code there
}
```

My question is:
How can I execute this method into another click event like:

```
private void dgvTaskAssign_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    tvProjectList_NodeMouseClick()
}
```

How can I send there the sender and `TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs`  is requested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the event method using the magic of [Control.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) / [Control.BeginInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2)  (I'm quoting someone else, here), using a [MethodInvoker Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2). This will execute its code.

You can also pass some arguments in the event method specific `EventArgs`, creating a new instance of that event arguments type.

Something like this:

```
private void dgvTaskAssign_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    treeView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
        tvProjectList_NodeMouseClick(this,
            new TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs(tvProjectList.SelectedNode, MouseButtons.Left, 1, 0, 0));
    });
}

private void tvProjectList_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Why did you click me this way!");
}
```

But you should probably consider what `Ctznkane525` is proposing in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to move the code from tvProjectList_NodeMouseClick into another method then call it in both places.

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    // Code Here
}

private void dgvTaskAssign_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    SomeMethod();
}

private void tvProjectList_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    SomeMethod();
}
```